# how to use bootstrap and kendo ui

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui, styling

I want to use KendoUI and bootstrap in my web application. I like kendo.material.css style. When I link bootstrap.css to be able to use bootstrap responsive features I also get some bootstrap styling i.e. blue border around a focused input. How to use these two frameworks without bootstrap specific styling (colors and so on)

Answer (score 3):

According to kendo, the best integration between should be achieved using:

1. Use the **kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css** instead of **kendo.common.css**. This ensures that the dimensions of Kendo UI are going to match match the ones in Bootstrap.
2. Use the **kendo.bootstrap.min.css** theme which applies the Bootstrap colors to the Kendo UI widgets.

For more information you can check here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap

Kendo also provide a themebuilder. You can find it here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/themebuilder

André

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do it: I had the following styles linked: 
bootstrap.css
kendo-material.css
kendo.common-bootstrap.css

It looks ok - no blue border when focusing an input. But form-control class does not set 100% width of an input. It is overriden by .k-textbox class of kendo.common-bootstrap.css and its width is 12.4em

Comment: @Marcin can you provide an example? a jsfiddle would be enough

Comment: Here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/p7ej5a9a/2/
The html code is the effect of something like this in cshtml file:
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty).HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "form-control"})

Comment: @Marcin like I mention in my answer (point number 2) you should include kendo.bootstrap.min.css.
Here is a live example of it working https://jsfiddle.net/p7ej5a9a/4/ 
I'm not quite sure if you should include as you did kendo.material.min.css but in this case it doesnt matter.

Comment: Thank you. I think that we misunderstand each other. I want to use kendo.material styling - I want the input to look like in my jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net/p7ej5a9a/2) example. As you can see in your example the styling is slightly different - there is a border around the input and it is glowing blue while focused. I want to use bootstrap framework to use its responsive features: classes like row, col-*, form-group, form-control and so on. What I want to achieve is to be able to apply k-textbox class to make the control look like in my fiddle but with 100% width because of form-control class.